# How long does it usually take for journals to resolve 'expressions of concern'?

Tags: peer-review, journals, publishers, journal-workflow, research-misconduct

The 'expression of concern' in question is [this one](https://academic.oup.com/rev/article/30/3/420/6360986). It says:

> The journal and publisher have been alerted to concerns about this article, and an investigation is in progress. In the interim, we alert readers that these concerns have been raised.

How long does this kind of issue usually take to resolve? The expression of concern was originally published on 1 September 2021, or more than six months ago, and it feels unusual for an investigation to still be ongoing.

I am not asking for a prediction as to how long this particular investigation will take (although that would answer the question), only for how long it usually took to resolve similar expressions of concern in the past.

Comment: "it feels unusual for an investigation to still be ongoing" [citation needed]. The Retraction Watch blog has taught me that the investigation can take years, sometimes many years.

Comment: @Roland e.g. the last paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDPI#Controversial_articles discusses an article which had an expression of concern addressed and resolved in a week. I don't have general statistics.

Comment: I'd expect that to be an exception. If it can be resolved that quickly, most journals won't even issue an expression of concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any comprehensive study that can authoritatively answer the general question

> How long does this kind of issue usually take to resolve?

across all fields. (There likely is field variation both in the incidence of expressions of concerns, as well as the time to resolution.) That said, here are two studies that may offer at least an idea.

- [Vaught, M., Jordan, D.C. & Bastian, H. Concern noted: a descriptive study of editorial expressions of concern in PubMed and PubMed Central, *Res. Integr. Peer Rev.* **2**, 10 (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1186/s41073-017-0030-2) studied the biomedical literature up to 2016 and found that around 25% of cases where an editorial expression of concern (EEoC) was issued lead to a retraction within the time period. With regards to these retractions, the authors write:

> More than half of these retractions occurred within the year after the primary EEoC was issued (n = 38, 61%), and 57 publications (92%) were retracted within 2 years of primary EEoC. The mean time from EEoC to retraction was 299 ± 245 days, and the median was 263 days with an IQR of 333. The longest gap between original EEoC and retraction was just under 3 years.

Note that Vaught, Jordan, and Bastian remain quiet on the time delay from an issued expression of concern to other resolutions. One issue they found is that publishers sometimes quietly remove expressions of concern, making it difficult to be sure just how many have been issued. This should be kept in mind when interpreting the statistical results.

- [Jaime A.Teixeira da Silva & Yuki Yamada An extended state of uncertainty: A snap-shot of expressions of concern in neuroscience, *Current Research in Behavioral Sciences* **2**, 100045 (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.crbeha.2021.100045) considered a smaller sample:

> Using the Retraction Watch database until April 20, 2021, we assessed 20 cases of EoCs in the neuroscience literature to appreciate how EoCs have been processed. After excluding one author-issued EoC, from 19 editor-issued EoCs, 10 were resolved in an average of 220 days while nine remain unresolved.

These authors also note that some expressions of concerns are not clearly labeled as such, complicating data collection.

---

In light of these numbers, an investigation taking more than six months would not be at all unusual. At the time of writing this answer, the expression of concern you cite was issued 236 days ago, which is also consistent with these averages. However, given the sample sizes and potential field variation, I would not necessarily assume that these averages would apply to the field of the article you mention. Further, as @Roland mentions in a comment, such numbers anecdotally agrees with what a reader of the [Retraction Watch](https://retractionwatch.com/) blog might expect, where investigations are often reported to take years.  I think the takeaway here and more generally is that the publishing system often appears to be slow in taking decisions regarding scientific errors in the published literature.